# Run weka classifiers using Windows cmd line

Tags: windows, command-line, weka

I want to run weka through the command line. I type in this command:

```
java -classpath weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t data/weather.arff -i
```

And I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/classifiers/tree
 s/J48
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.classifiers.trees.J48
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
   Could not find the main class: weka.classifiers.trees.J48.  Program will exit.
```

My classpath variable is set to C:\Program Files\Weka-3-4\mysql-connector-java-3.1.8-bin.jar

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: That's not DOS. DOS is extinct. It probably has support for ancient Java versions only

Comment: Nothing anymore, I fixed your tags/title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your command shell in the same directory as weka.jar?

You get that message if java simply can't find weka.jar

go

```
dir weka.jar
```

and check that the command shell can find it.

If not, you need to cd to the folder that contains weka.jar

Or you could put the full path to weka.jar

```
$java -classpath /"your-weka-path"/weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t data/weather.arff -i
```